# JfreeChart timing charts are rendered in hours and seconds

Tags: jfreechart

[image]

This is what I need. Obviously, it is written with a JavaScript plugin,

But my requirement is to write it in Java. I came across the jfree chart plugin.

My requirement: Divide the hours into intervals,
draw the chart in seconds for rendering,
I don't know where to start now. I can now render once every hour,

But I don't know how to divide the hour and use the seconds to render the chart.

Thank you for reviewing my question and looking forward to your reply

Comment: Using a `ChartFactory`, create a time series chart and invoke `setDateFormatOverride()` with the desired format, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20setdateformatoverride). If this is not a duplicate, please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: Thank you very much for finding a better way to write the time period directly in:
timeSeries.addOrUpdate(new Second(date),1.0);
Then in:
dateaxis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm"));
Just set the display time

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.